# What's the meaning this DOT notation?

Tags: model-theory, automata, fixed-point-theorems

I'm reading a chapter in a Model Checking book.
I came across this chapter "Symbolic Model Checking", in which the author mentions Fixed Point representation.

[I don't know how to explain the context, so I took a photo of that paragraph instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNCCQ.jpg)

In another example that I found:

[This example talks about reachability games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x8CJ.jpg)

I really appreciate your help.

Thang

Comment: $\mu Z.\tau(Z)$ is not an "operation": it is a "complete" symbol meaning: "the least $Z$ such that..."

Comment: See [$\mu$ operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C_operator).

Comment: should I look at $\tau$ operator too?

Comment: No; $\tau$ is the mapping; they use $\nu$ for the "maximal", but I think that it is not standard.

Comment: right, that makes sense to what I read in the book. Thanks Mauro.

Comment: So in summary, all that dot (in $\mu$Z.$\tau$(Z)) means is basically "such that"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that dots in these two examples might have a different meaning.

The first one looks very much like a dot from [Lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), and given that the chapter talks about fixpoints, I find that highly probable. If this is the case, then the dot is only a delimiter, and it is to indicate that the symbols that come between the operator ($\nu$ or $\mu$ in your example, or $\lambda$ in lambda calculus) are variables bound by that particular operator. To give you a more common example, you can write quantifiers like this: $\forall x. \phi(x)$ instead of $\forall x (\phi(x))$, $\forall x : \phi(x)$ or yet some other notation.

The second dot seems like some kind of conjunction, perhaps a composition of states, or sequence concatenation or something similar, there should be an explanation before in the text.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: what do you think they mean in the second context? There is no explanation prior to this though

Comment: @csessh I still think there should be some description. Find the place where it appears for the first time, maybe there? Check carefully, it might be easy to overlook, for example "let $\langle \mathcal{S}, \cdot, \varepsilon \rangle$ be a monoid such that ..."

Comment: It's actually the first time it appears. http://i.stack.imgur.com/5aAkl.jpg

Comment: @csessh Maybe in some other chapter, when dealing with sequences or sets? What is the title of the book?

Comment: The book is Model Checking by Edmund M. Clarke. But the screenshot I took is from a past exam paper. I'm looking through other chapters of the book right now.